# C++ Checking a function's "flag argument"

Tags: c++

How can we create or show an error or a warning telling the user that he/she can not input flags that have the opposite value of another, already input flag? How can we show that the user has used an invalid argument?

An example demonstrating the problem:

```
struct Flags
{
    enum Values
    {
        None = 0,
        Yes = 1,
        No = 2,
        Good = 4,
        Bad = 8
    };
};

void Function( __in int p_Flag )
{
    if( p_Flag & Flags::Yes )
        std::cout << "Yes\n";
    else if( p_Flag & Flags::No )
        std::cout << "No\n";

    if( p_Flag & Flags::Good )
        std::cout << "Good\n";
    else if( p_Flag & Flags::Bad )
        std::cout << "Bad\n";
};

int main( void )
{
    Function( Flags::Yes | Flags::No );         // Error/warning (not OK)
    Function( Flags::Good | Flags::Bad );       // Error/warning (not OK)
    Function( Flags::Yes | Flags::Bad );        // OK!
    
    return( 0 );
};
```

Although the first opposite flag will be chosen over the other, we should still show a warning or an error, to ensure that the user knows which flag he/she really needed.

```
Function( Flags::Yes | Flags::No );
```

Comment: static_assert may be worth looking at

Comment: You could simply document that some flags take priority over others, i.e., the presence of A implicitly disables B.

Comment: Are you talking about compile-time warnings?

Comment: There is no way to issue compile-time warnings based on function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cassert>

assert(p_Flag & (Flags::Yes|Flags::No) != (Flags::Yes|Flags::No))
```